# Display all data from child node on a tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble displaying all of the followers of user on a table view cell with their profile picture and full name (similar to instagram).

A snippet of my firebase JSON structure is:

```
 "followers" : {
    "FoFQDAGGX9hntBiBdXYCBHd8yas2" : {
      "CjeP35ceAQZJuUPhm7U1eF3Yq4F3" : true,
      "FjS4wUpXAUa5aWwXkjvujHxE4He2" : true,
      "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2" : true,
      "PqMkClaPM3W8k7ZSgzAHb3yne5D3" : true,
      "buS4recuDpdg60ckFqwjoU344TC2" : true
    },
 "users" : {
    "CjeP35ceAQZJuUPhm7U1eF3Yq4F3" : {
      "email" : "bbbb@gmail.com",
      "fullname" : "Bbbb",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pinion-4896b.appspot.com/o/profile_image%2FCjeP35ceAQZJuUPhm7U1eF3Yq4F3?alt=media&token=0449c633-b397-4452-b2df-41f3a5390084",
      "work" : "Nottingham",
    },
```

Code in the table view cell (FollowersTableViewCell):

```
@IBOutlet weak var followersProfileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var followersNameLabel: UILabel!

var user: UserModel? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}
func updateView() {
    followersNameLabel.text = user?.fullname
    if let photoUrlString = user?.profileImageUrl {
        let photoUrl = URL(string: photoUrlString)
        followersProfileImage.sd_setImage(with: photoUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderImg"))
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Code in view controller (FollowersViewController)

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var users: [UserModel] = []

func loadusers() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    var followersNames = [String]()
    var profileImage = [String]()

    let followersRef = ref.child("followers").child(currentUser) //retreives all nodes in the following node
    followersRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.children.allObjects)
        for child in snapshot.children { //build the array of keys
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key

            let userRef = ref.child("users").child(key) //get the user name and profile image from the users node
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let followersName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
                let followersProfileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String
                print(followersName)
                print(followersProfileImageUrl)

                followersNames.append(followersName)
                profileImage.append(followersProfileImageUrl)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    })
}
extension FollowersViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FollowersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FollowersTableViewCell
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.user = user
    return cell
  }
}
```

Now the code runs and the profile picture and fullname of the followers are printed on the console but doesn't show anything on the table view of the app - thanks in advance :)

Update: 
User model definition

```
class UserModel {
    var email: String?
    var work: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
    var fullname: String?
    var id: String?
}
extension UserModel {
    static func transformUser(dict: [String: Any], key: String) -> UserModel {
        let user = UserModel()
        user.email = dict["email"] as? String
        user.work = dict["work"] as? String
        user.profileImageUrl = dict["profileImageUrl"] as? String
        user.fullname = dict["fullname"] as? String
        user.id = key
        return user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TableView does not display any data because you don't populate `users` array at any point.

I might want to instantiate an UserModel object in `observeSingleEvent` implementation, add the object to `users` array and invoke `reloadData` (or `insertRows`) method also right after that. (Instead of outside the implementation block)

As requested, here is a quick (and dirty) way to create an user object and refresh the UI

```
let user = UserModel()
user.fullname = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as? String
user.profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as? String

self.users.append(user)
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I got an error saying “Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UserModel’” so instead i created 2 arrays for the followers names and profile images - now the names print in the console but not on the app. I have added the edit to the code above

Comment: you have to create an instance of class UserModel, can you attach the class definition?

Comment: Your code still knows to display UserModel objects, populating followersNames and profileImage not doing any good

Comment: Oh i see thanks, I have attached the UserModel class - i'm quite new to this so appreciate your help

Comment: Would it be better to create a new model instead of using the UserModel?